# how do I tell visual studio code to show intellisense for built in python functions like range()

Tags: python

I am entering a line in Visual Studio Code that contains the range function.
I was expecting to see it show me the arguments for the range function. 
Instead, I see in a dropdown, where I can click range in the dropdown list.
And after that it fills in start, stop, range for the arguments for the function.
This means I have to change these values.
I was hoping the IDE would show me what the valid arguments are.
Am i missing something ?

Comment: IDE cant read your mind, obviously you need to set values from which number you want to start range and where to end

Comment: Have you installed the python extension for vscode?

Comment: Yes I have install the extension. It is interesting. If I type int() float() len()  tuple() etc I do get A popup showing the arguments. But range() comes up with range() and does not indicate what is happening with range. I will be able to live with it. Looks like there are just some values that do not show the arguments and what they are.

Comment: Trying hovering just before the first parens after the keyword. Just after `range` and before `(`. That should work.

Comment: You can also just run `help(range)` in the Python terminal. The arguments are at the very top of the page.

Answer (score 2):

I use the **VS Code Extension** `IntelliSense (Pylance)` whose owner is `Microsoft`. This is the best extension for *auto completion* and *functions/modules description*
[Extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-python.python)

If you have this extension and still facing the same issue then try reinstalling.
Don't use the web version of VS Code.
Restart once after installation is finished.
Also make sure to have `Python` installed on your system.

While writing the `range() function`
[image]

While hovering over the `range() function`
[image]

Answer (score 2):

I personally use an autocomplete engine known as TabNine. I used to use Kite, and the built in intellisense provided with the VSCode IDE, however, TabNine has proved very reliable to me, and has built-in support for many modules. You can download it in the extensions section of VSCode, by looking up TabNine.
[This](https://tabnine.com) is the official TabNine website.